# For loop in R only working for the last index number

Tags: r

So I'm working on an Coursera assignment for an R course.

I'm using a for loop to try to create a data frame that combines the data of 332 csv files. 
The for loop only returns the data frame of the last (332th) csv file. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {

  files <- Sys.glob("specdata//*.csv")

  ## Create empty numeric vector to append the nitrate values
  nitr <- numeric()
  ## Create empty numeric vector to append the sulfate values
  sulf <- numeric()

  for (j in 1:length(files)) {
    read.data <- read.csv(files[j])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `directory` and `threshold` are defined as arguments but not used.
2. `nitr` and `sulf` are created but not used
3. to get such a list of files `list.files("specdata", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE)` is usually used
4. For every iteration, `files[j]` is read (and replaces former one) but nothing is done then.
5. Also your function should return something.
6. I don't think you really need a function, the code below should do the job.

```

```
files <- list.files("specdata", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE)
res <- vector("list", length(files))
for (j in 1:length(files)) { # or seq_along(files)
  res[[j]] <- read.csv(files[j])
}
res
```

```

Actually this:

```
lapply(list.files("specdata", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE), read.csv)
```

would probably work just as fine and is by far less verbose and has a lovely R accent. If you need more arguments for `read.csv`, eg `header=TRUE` you can add them (named and comma-separated) after the function name:

```
lapply(list.files("specdata", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE), read.csv, header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy one, you're overwriting read.data each iteration of the loop. You probably want something like:

```
files <- Sys.glob("specdata//*.csv")

## Create empty numeric vector to append the nitrate values
nitr <- numeric()
## Create empty numeric vector to append the sulfate values
sulf <- numeric()

out <- vector("list")

for (j in 1:length(files)) {
  out[[j]] <- read.csv(files[j])
}
```

A good way to debug for loops is to set j equal to 1, run through the body of the loop, then set it equal to 2 and do the same thing. Also you might want to use `seq_along(files)` instead of `1:length(files)` the former can give you bad results when files is of length 0.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be the fastest way to do this. This will also show a progress bar of the task being done.

```
library(data.table)
library(pbapply)


# get file names
  files <- list.files("c:/your_folder", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE)

# read and pile all files 
  dt <- rbindlist(pblapply(files, fread))
```